# How to Deploy EFS-Provisioner with PVC working

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, cloud, amazon-eks

I have successfully deployed `efs-provisioner` following the steps outlined in [efs-provisioner](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/tree/master/aws/efs).

[image]

But the PVC is hanging in `Pending` State displaying the same message:

`waiting for a volume to be created, either by external provisioner "example.com/aws-efs" or manually created by system administrator`.

[image]

What could be a reason why PVC is not created properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was described by ParaSwarm posted [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-storage/issues/754#issuecomment-418207930)

> *"...The quick fix is to give the cluster-admin role to the default service account. Of course, depending on your environment and
>   security, you may need a more elaborate fix. If you elect to go the
>   easy way, you can simply apply this:"*

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: default-admin-rbac (or whatever)
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```